# Having trouble copying entire row of data from one sheet to another using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to organize my spending and my first sheet in my excel document contains all of my purchases. I have "Date" in column A, "Expense Category" in Column B, "Detail" in column C and "Cost" in Column D. I want to copy an entire row to Sheet 2 if Column B has the word "Gas".

I have tried to look up this question and found code from the following link:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3723-excel-move-row-to-another-sheet-based-on-cell-value.html#a1

I have tried to update the code to reflect my data but I just began learning VBA and am getting the "Subscript out of range" error and the "I = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count is being highlighted yellow.

This is my code currently, based on the websites code for copying rows to other sheets:

```
Sub MoveRowBasedOnCellValue()

Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim K As Long
I = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
J = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If J = 1 Then
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange) = 
  0 Then J = 0
End If
Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B" & I)
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For K = 1 To xRg.Count
If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Gas" Then
    xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Desitination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & J + 1)
    J = J + 1
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What line does the error occur on?  Also, take out (or comment out) `On Error Resume Next` to see other errors that occur - if they do, let us know what error at what line.  Also, what do you expect `xRg(K)` to do?  That will select the `K` row *of* that range.

Comment: Sorry I just updated my original post. I get the error on "I = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count" line. Also I'm not really sure what to expect this is my first macro I'm doing that I'm not just simply following along :(.

Comment: Try `Worksheets(1).UsedRange...` you may not have a "Sheet1".

Comment: So that made me no longer get an error (thank you), but the macro is not doing anything when I run it D:

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to change

```
For K = 1 To xRg.Count
If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Gas" Then
    xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & J + 1)
    J = J + 1
End If
```

For:

```
For each KCell in xRg
If KCell.Value = "Gas" Then
    KCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & J + 1)
    J = J + 1
End If
Next KCell
```

(looping through each cell in `xRg`)

Comment: I am still getting the Subscript error (don't know what that means) on "I = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

Comment: Do you have a Worksheet called "Sheet1"? if not, then replace "Sheet1" with the name of the sheet.

Comment: I had changed the worksheets to "Kevin Expenses" and "Gas" but I thought that they could still be called sheet1 and sheet2 because of their location on the document (guess I was wrong). Now there is no error, but nothing happens when I run the code.

Comment: @KevinBrad - If you use `Worksheets("SOME NAME")` then it's going to explicitly refer to a worksheet called "SOME NAME".  If you're trying to use the tabs' location (aka "Index"), you use `Worksheets(1)`.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful information. Now my problem is that nothing happens when I run the code, which probably has to do with the fact that I don't know what I am expected xRg(K) to do. I tried to change the code based on the answer but it didn't work.

Comment: @KevinBrad if the sheets exist in `ThisWorkbook` (the book with the VBA code) at compile-time, then you already have a global-scope identifier for it. Give every sheet a `CodeName` by editing their `(Name)` property (F4), so if you call it `KevinExpensesSheet`, then you can do `KevinExpensesSheet.Range(...)` and your code will work regardless of what you rename the worksheet's tab in Excel, and regardless of its index.

Comment: @KevinBrad - See this [quick .gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGm1s.gif) which hopefully clarifies the Index vs Sheet name.  Also, `xRg(1)` will select the FIRST CELL in `xRg`.  So, if you have `Set xRg = Range("A10:A100")`, then `xRg(1).EntireRow.Copy` will copy row `10`.  `xRg(10)` will be row `20`.

Comment: Okay thank you, now I am using Worksheets(1) and Worksheets(2) and keeping the sheets indexed properly to limit confusion atm. I am not really following the second part of your comment. If I'm following the code I have, xRg has been set to equal my data's column B. I think the For K = 1 Loop is making it so that it checks for the word "Gas" in each row of the column. I don't see where the problem is unfortunately.